# WebView's postUrl method only works with explicit string

Tags: java, android, string, authentication, webview

I can already tell this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to login to a web page using `postUrl()` and when I explicitly write the post data like this:

```
String postData = "username=johndoe&password=mypassword";
myWebview.postUrl("https://moodle.domain.com/login/index.php", postData.getBytes());
```

It works, but if I construct the postData using variables:

```
String postData = "username="+user+"&password="+pass;
myWebview.postUrl("https://moodle.domain.com/login/index.php", postData.getBytes());
```

It doesn't work. Wrong credentials. I've verified that both strings have the exact same value and I tried using UTF-8.

I just don't understand, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: if the first one works, then the second one should work as well. What I'm guessing is that the browser stores data which prevents the second method from working. Try clearing the WebView data (or simply reinstall your app). This time, only test the second method

Comment: So in the second case `user.equals("johndoe")`and `pass.equals("mypassword")` are both `true`? Have you verified the behaviour server side? Do you have server side access to be able to step with a debugger and check what the server is actually seeing (and doing)?

Comment: I have uninstalled the app and tried only with the second method, invalid login. I don't have acces to the server side. Also, there is this warning -> W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f0a0030, entry index(48) is beyond type entryCount(14)
                Failure getting entry for 0x7f0a0030 (t=9 e=48) (error -75)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look Like, the 'user' or the 'pass' has invisible symbols. You need:

1) Check string using `equals`:

```
 String postData1 = "username=johndoe&password=mypassword";
 String postData2 = "username="+user+"&password="+pass;
 System.out.println(postData1.equals(postData2));
```

2) Try to find invisible symbols, for example:

```
 String postData1 = "username=johndoe&password=mypassword";
 String postData2 = "username="+user+"&password="+pass;
 char[] arr1 = postData1.toCharArray();
 char[] arr2 = postData1.toCharArray();

 for (int i=0; i< Math.max(arr1.length(), arr2.length(); i++ ) {
     if(arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
         System.out.println("Different i " + i);
     } 
 }
```

Comment: You are right, I've checked the length of both strings and the first was 38, the second 45...when I printed the value couldn't see the damn empty spaces al the end. I just used postData.trim().getBytes() and it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
String postData = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_username, "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_password, "UTF-8");
 webview.postUrl("https://moodle.domain.com/login/index.php",postData.getBytes());
```